# Making the div adjust within a given width and rest should break to next row

Tags: html, css

I have an existing design in our project. We have 4 number of div, those are aligned in two row and two cols.

But as per clients new requirement, we can have multiple div and the container containing it should allow 100% width and the inner div need to adjust within that width side by side, and if the width is not sufficient then remaining div should break down and start another row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>
    <div class="block3"></div>
    <div class="block4"></div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
.block1 {
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    background: #FF0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.block2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    background: #FF0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.block3 {
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    background: #FF0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.block4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    background: #FF0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This resembles our existing design. http://jsfiddle.net/NE3rZ/

Please suggest how can i make the above design responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the inner divs to float left to each other `{ float: left }`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Then your css

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.block {
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    background: #FF0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/NE3rZ/2/. You can try resizing the width.

Comment: Wow... its like bullet :)